# Unity - How can I popup a GUI button when a target is detected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am new to Unity and Vuforia. I am trying to create an augmented reality experience where the user can scan across a target marker and it will reveal a button that they can click on. I have found couple of programs but it throws an error related to ITrackableEventHandler.

****Error**: Assets\scripts\ButtonPopup.cs(5,43): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ITrackableEventHandler' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ButtonPopup : MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler {
    
    private TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;
    
    private bool mShowGUIButton = false;
    private Rect mButtonRect = new Rect(50,50,120,60);
    
    void Start () {
        mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
        if (mTrackableBehaviour)
        {
            mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
        }
    }
    
    public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
                                    TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
                                    TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
    {
        if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED)
        {
            mShowGUIButton = true;
        }
        else
        {
            mShowGUIButton = false;
        }
    }
    
    void OnGUI() {
        if (mShowGUIButton) {
            // draw the GUI button
            if (GUI.Button(mButtonRect, "Hello")) {
                // do something on button click 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try to solve this pretty clear error message (`ITrackableEventHandler` unknown) ?

Answer (score 0):

- I think you might be missing a namespace like

  ```
  using Vuforia;
  ```
- afaik the `RegisterTrackableEventHandler` is deprecated and now it is `RegisterOnTrackableStatusChanged` without the need for the interface maybe it's deprecated as well)
- and `OnGUI` (also IMGUI) is pretty much obsolete/legacy and mainly only used for editor scripts and very very quick and dirty prototyping .. rather use the ["new" UI System (uGUI)](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/com.unity.ugui.html) using the [UI package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/index.html) and then just use `SetActive`

So first of all you would need to set up a [`Button`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-Button.html) within a [`Canvas`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/UICanvas.html) somewhere in your Scene. If you go via `Hierarchy View` → <kbd>right click</kbd> → <kbd>Create</kbd> →  <kbd>UI</kbd> → <kbd>Button</kbd> this automatically creates a new `Canvas` if you don't have any so far and adds a Button to it.

And the code would be somewhat like

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Vuforia;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ButtonPopup : MonoBehaviour
{    
    [SerializeField] private TrackableBehaviour _trackableBehaviour;
    
    // Reference your Button via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private Button _button;
    
    private void Start () 
    {
        if(!_trackableBehaviour)
        {
            if(!TryGetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>(out  _trackableBehaviour))
        {
            Debug.LogError("No TrackableBehavior!", this);
            return;
        }

        _trackableBehaviour.RegisterOnTrackableStatusChanged(OnTrackableStateChanged);
    }
    
    private void OnTrackableStateChanged(TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus, TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
    {
        _button.gameObject.SetActive(newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED || newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED);
    }
}
```

Of course if you really have your reasons you can stick to the `OnGUI` .. it's just really not the state of the art ;)